# What's the difference between `git log -- some_file` and `git log --follow some_file`?

Tags: git

What's the difference between `git log -- some_file` and `git log --follow some_file`? Their outputs look pretty similar, except maybe `git log --follow some_file` is more-specific and doesn't show merge commits?

`man git log` shows:

> ```
> git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>...]
> ```

> ```
>   --follow
>       Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If a file was renamed, `--follow` will make `git log` keep following its history back beyond the commit where it was renamed. Without `--follow`, the log will end because the path no longer matches.

In the absence of renames, `--follow` doesn't change anything.

Comment: `In the absence of renames, --follow doesn't change anything.` That's good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_options

> --follow
>
> Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file).